# what are this updates?

Tags: updates, update-manager

i am new to ubuntu...

i recently install ubuntu 13.10. ,after installing ubuntu ,i got a notification that update are available.the notification come from software updater app,i got 2 updates,one is come yesterday and other one come today,i update the first update ,after i got another update today,i wait and post this question..

are this updates send by ubuntu ?
are this updates are software(apps) updates ?
is it safe to update ?

Comment: @xangua: The user does not specifically ask for security updates, they are updates in general. Does it still qualify as a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

No,those updates are from the developers, but normally they are safe, if you just installed ubuntu, you didn't add ppa (others sources) so you just have officials ppa that are trustful. So we can consider all those updates by safe and it's recommended to do them. And for your second question, those updates can be for software, the system or the kernel.